# Downloading files from another dropbox account

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I got a dropbox-link with some files, protected by password.
I got the link, the password, dropbox business account, and App key, App secret that i got from creating a new App in https://www.dropbox.com/developers/

What is the next step?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download a file from a Dropbox shared link programmatically, you can use the [/2/sharing/get_shared_link_file](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-get_shared_link_file) endpoint. (That's the HTTPS endpoint itself, but if you're using one of [the official Dropbox API v2 SDKs](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation), there will be a corresponding method.)

This endpoint is accessible via Dropbox API apps, as well "Team member file access" Dropbox Business API apps, via [the "Member file access" feature](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/teams#teams-member-file-access). Other Dropbox Business API apps cannot call this endpoint.